# About factorising permutations into transpositions

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Let $c(\pi)$ stand for the number of cycles in the unique disjoint cycle representation of $\pi.$

Consider $\pi \in S_n$ and $\pi = \tau_1 \tau_2\ldots \tau_a.$ Then $a\equiv n - c(\pi)\pmod 2$. In other words $a$ and $n - c(\pi)$ have the same parity "and so two different decompositions of $\pi$ into transpositions will both have an even or both have an odd number of terms."

I am a bit confused about how they derived the conclusion in the quote above. Can someone, please, elaborate a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\pi\in S_n$ let $f(\pi)=n-c(\pi)$; this really is a number that depends only on $\pi$ itself. Now suppose that we decompose $\pi$ as a product of transpositions in two ways,

$$\pi=\tau_1\tau_2\ldots\tau_a=\tau_1'\tau_2'\ldots\tau_b'\;.$$

The result says that $a\equiv f(\pi)\pmod2$ and $b\equiv f(\pi)\pmod2$, so $a\equiv f(\pi)\equiv b\pmod2$, and since congruence mod $2$ is an equivalence relation, this says that $a\equiv b\pmod2$. But that just means that $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder on division by $2$, so either $a$ and $b$ are both even, or $a$ and $b$ are both odd.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott. Thank you. The answer is very clear. I have one more question. Consider the fact that $c(\pi \tau) = c(\pi) \pm 1.$ Apparantly, it's used in this proof [here](https://s13.postimg.org/mxkf78vnb/444.png) which then implies [this theorem](https://s21.postimg.org/jkrxubtd3/123.png). Can you elaborate a little what's going on here. Thanks.

Comment: @JJWQ: You’re welcome. Perhaps the easiest way to see what’s going on in that argument is to look at that final calculation $$\underbrace{1\pm 1\pm 1\pm\cdots\pm 1}_{a\text{ terms}}$$ mod $2$: $1\equiv-1\pmod2$, so $$\underbrace{1\pm 1\pm 1\pm\cdots\pm 1}_{a\text{ terms}}\equiv\underbrace{1+1+1+\cdots+1}_{a\text{ terms}}\equiv a\pmod2\;.$$

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott, both $\pi = \tau_1 \tau_2 \tau_3 \ldots \tau_a$ and $\pi = \ell_1 \ell_2 \ell_3 \ldots \ell_{n - c(\pi)}$ have either odd or even number of transpositions because $a$ and $n - c(\pi)$ have the same parity because $n - c(\pi)\equiv a\pmod 2$ because $1 \pm 1 \pm 1 \pm 1 \ldots \pm 1 \equiv a\pmod 2$ because $n - c(\pi) = 1 \pm 1 \pm 1 \pm 1 \ldots \pm 1$, right? How do we calculate $n - c(\pi)$?

Comment: @JJWQ: You need to find $c(\pi)$, which means finding the unique decomposition of $\pi$ into disjoint cycles and counting the cycles. That’s a pretty mechanical procedure.